# How to adapt to file structure differences between java package projects

Tags: java

My background is mainly in JavaScript and I was looking into working with Java.  While I've worked with the language before on a basic level, I haven't played with actual applications and one of the more mind-boggling things is the file structure and the significance of the naming of folders such as `controller`, `entity`, `gateway`, `repository`, `service`, and `model`.  It seems as if file structure between projects can vary wildly as well as how folders with the names that I just listed can be arranged considerably differently from one project to another.  For example, I see something like this:

```
├── common
├── config
├── controller
│   ├── helper
│   ├── request
│   └── response
├── core
│   └── service
├── entity
│   └── spec
├── exception
├── exceptionmapper
├── flow
├── gateway
│   └── entity
├── helpers
├── repository
│   └── mysql
│       └── dao
├── schema
├── script
├── service
├── transform
└── utils
```

and yet another like this:

```
└── service
    ├── api
    ├── config
    ├── core
    │   ├── enums
    │   ├── models
    │   ├── queue
    │   │   ├── exceptions
    │   │   └── local
    │   ├── services
    │   │   └── impl
    │   ├── statemachine
    │   ├── utils
    │   └── workflow
    │       └── tasks
    ├── gateway
    │   └── exceptions
    ├── health
    ├── repository
    │   ├── dao
    │   ├── entity
    │   ├── jpa
    │   └── models
    └── resources
```

I'm wondering what drives these file structures as they, to me, seem radically different, although both are for RESTful apis and how I might be able to adapt from one package to another.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the second part of your post:

> I'm wondering what drives these file structures

Well, currently there is no standard of packages structure across different projects, so only conventions and will of the programmer determine this structure.

Some modern build tools (Maven, Gradle) do some assumption about folders to place the source code in (customizable in general case, but at least you have a reasonable convention). For instance, there are `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java` `src/test/resources` folders.

However, these tools don't make assumptions about the internal actual package structure, that in an ideal case can help to understand how the project is really divided

> I was wondering if file structures for projects/packages can be identified by framework

Now, some frameworks can do some rudimentary job on this.
Take a look at Spring Boot, for example.

It comes with conventions of recognition of Beans only if they are in a package "beneath" the package that contains the main class, for example:

```
|__com
   |__app
       |__myapp
       |     |__ Main.java // spring boot application main class 
       |     |__web        // will search for beans here by default
       |     |__businesslogic // will search for beans here by default
       |     |__dao           // will search for beans here by default
       |__somepackage         // won't search for beans here by default
             |__...
```

Other frameworks might also make some assumptions, Spring boot is just an example.